# how to use shared preference on multi textview,multi checkbox,multi button and multi edit box in android?

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox, editbox

\how use sharedpreferences on all field?

1. Layout XML:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="75dp" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="1." />

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView6"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="00:00" 
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView11"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="00:00" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/editText1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="www.google.co.in"
           android:ems="10" >

           <requestFocus />
       </EditText>
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="75dp" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="2." />

       <CheckBox
           android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView7"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:text="00:00" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView12"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="00:00" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/editText2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="www.yahoo.co.in"
           android:ems="10" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```

   ```
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button2"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.11"
           android:text="WebView" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. main activicty

package com.example.myproject5;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv6, tv7, tv11, tv12;
    private EditText et1, et2;
    private CheckBox cb1, cb2;
    private Button submit, webview;
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    private static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    private static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID1 = 2;
    private static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID2 = 3;
    private static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID3 = 4;
    int cur = 0;
    private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
    private int savelogin;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tv7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tv11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        tv12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        webview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tv6.setEnabled(false);
        tv7.setEnabled(false);
        tv11.setEnabled(false);
        tv12.setEnabled(false);
        et1.setEnabled(false);
        et2.setEnabled(false);

        loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        savelogin = loginPreferences.getInt("abc", 0); // save data
        if (savelogin == 1) {
            tv6.setText(savelogin);
        } else if (savelogin == 2) {
            tv7.setText(savelogin);
        } else if (savelogin == 3) {
            tv11.setText(0);
        } else if (savelogin == 4) {
            tv12.setText(0);
        }

        cb1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cb1.isChecked()) {
                    tv6.setEnabled(true);
                    tv11.setEnabled(true);
                    et1.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    tv6.setEnabled(false);
                    tv11.setEnabled(false);
                    et1.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
        });
        cb2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cb2.isChecked()) {
                    tv7.setEnabled(true);
                    tv12.setEnabled(true);
                    et2.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    tv7.setEnabled(false);
                    tv12.setEnabled(false);
                    et2.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
        });
        tv6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
                loadpreferences1("abc", 1);
            }
        });
        tv7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID1);
                loadpreferences1("abc", 2);

            }
        });
        tv11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID2);
                loadpreferences1("abc", 3);

            }
        });
        tv12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID3);
                loadpreferences1("abc", 4);

            }
        });

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        webview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, second.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                loadpreferences1("abc", 5);
            }
        });

    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                cur = TIME_DIALOG_ID;
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, true);

            case TIME_DIALOG_ID1:
                cur = TIME_DIALOG_ID1;
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, true);

            case TIME_DIALOG_ID2:
                cur = TIME_DIALOG_ID2;
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute, true);

            case TIME_DIALOG_ID3:
                cur = TIME_DIALOG_ID3;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            hour = selectedHour;
            minute = selectedMinute;
            if (cur == TIME_DIALOG_ID) {
                tv6.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));

            } else if (cur == TIME_DIALOG_ID1) {
                tv7.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));
            } else if (cur == TIME_DIALOG_ID2) {
                tv11.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));
            } else if (cur == TIME_DIALOG_ID3) {
                tv12.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour)).append(":").append(pad(minute)));
            }

        }
    };

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

    private void loadpreferences1(String str, int in) {
        loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
        loginPrefsEditor.putInt(str, in);
        loginPrefsEditor.commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these method to save and get values from any where in your app change parameter according to your requirment

this method to save value in shared prefrences

```
public static void setPref(Context c, String pref, String val) {
    Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).edit();
    e.putString(pref, val);
    e.commit();
}
```

this method to get value from shared prefrences

```
public static String getPref(Context c, String pref, String val) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c).getString(pref,
            val);
}
```

Comment: how to use in this program??

Comment: first create these two function in your app and then where you want to set value in prefrence call setPref function and where you want to get value call getPref

Comment: c refer to context you use this or your activityName.this

Comment: did you get the desired result